# How to add a timer to a Kick command | Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

Im trying to make a timed kick command, so the user gets kicked after either 24 hours, one week, or one month of time, but im unsure the best way to do this. The code I have right now doesnt work (because of the timer, otherwise it works fine):

````
const minute = 60 * second;
const hour = 60 * minute;
const day = 24 * hour; 

module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    
    execute(message, args){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(target){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            .then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: minute })
              })
              .catch(console.error)
            };

            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("User has been kicked");
        else{
            message.channel.send(`You coudn't kick that member!`)
        }```

thanks everyone!

p.s: this is discord.js
````

Comment: I need this. Can you share how did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method calls a function after a specified number of milliseconds.`setTimeout(function, milliseconds)`. So according to your case, it would be `setTimeout(memberTarget.kick(),1000)` where 1000 is time in milliseconds(ms). 1000ms = 1sec.